# Inverse permutation wrong solution on codesignal?

Tags: python, arrays, permutation

i'm currently doing the inversePermutation challenge on codesignal. Here a brief resume of the task:

Given a permutation, produce its inverse permutation.

Example

For permutation = [1, 3, 4, 2], the output should be
inversePermutation(permutation) = [1, 4, 2, 3].

In the solutions given by other users, I see this:

```
return numpy.argsort(*eval(dir()[0])) + 1
```

But I don't think that's correct, because even if the code pass the following test:
input [1, 3, 4, 2] expected output: [1, 4, 2, 3]
input [1, 2, 3] expected output: [1, 2, 3]
which are the only test veriefed by codesignal to pass the challenge, when I try this code with the following array: [3, 0, 2, 7] I get this: [2, 3, 1, 4]. Which is completly wrong according to the challenge description. I expected this output instead: [3, 2, 7, 0].

So how can I do this and is this code wrong or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try this code with the following array: [3, 0, 2, 7] I get this: [2, 3, 1, 4]. Which is completly wrong according to the challenge description. I expected this output instead: [3, 2, 7, 0].

If you pass an array with 4 values, the inverse permutation cannot have any values beyond 4, because these are the indices where to get the elements to restore the original order, not the elements.

So if you take `[3, 0, 2, 7]`, the correct answer is `[2, 3, 1, 4]`, because that means you take the second element (0), then third (2), then first (3) and finally forth (7) to make `[0, 2, 3, 7]`.

Comment: Thank you! I unterstand it now.

Answer (score 1):

From an online definition: "An inverse permutation is a permutation which you will get by inserting position of an element at the position specified by the element value in the array"

I have the feeling the input expected is a sequence of n numbers with n in range(1, n).

In your example you are including 0 and numbers exceeding list.len()